# Does Mathematica have a LogSumExp function that's numerically stable?

Tags: functions, numerics, machine-learning

I searched "Mathematica [LogSumExp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp)", and literally nothing is coming up. It's a relatively important function in machine learning and for numerically stable computation. Will I just have to implement it myself?

Comment: I wrote a version for the neural net functionality a while back. You can use it as a [ResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/LogSumExpLayer/)

Comment: You could [call](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExecuteAPythonFileWithExternalEvaluate.html) the [NumPy implementation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html)

Comment: There's ``Optimization`LogSumExp``.

Answer (score 4):

I just made the answer for myself, since it's not too hard. Still, Mathematica really should provide a native implementation.

```
LogSumExp[x_] := With[{m = Max[x]}, m + Log[Total @ Exp[x - m]]];
```

The input `x` has to be a list (e.g. `x={1, 2, 3}`. The max stuff is to keep things numerically stable.

Comment: It's probably neater to do `With[{m = Max[x]}, ...]` so you don't have to compute the Max twice

Comment: Replace `Plus @@` with `Total @` and it will be faster, esp. on large data.

Comment: LogSumExp[x_] := Log[Total@Exp[x]]